# ajax response status is 200 but triggers error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reactjs

I have a Reactjs project and I'm using ajax to fetch data from my php api.
the status is 200 and the response is json , but it triggers error:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 class User extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={username:'someone'}
}
click_btn=()=> {
   /* fetch("http://localhost/react/api/insert.php")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    username: result.name
                });
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    username:'error'
                });
            }
        )*/
   $.ajax({
       url:"http://localhost/react/api/insert.php",
       type:'post',
       dataType:'json',
       success:function (data, status,x) {
           alert(data.name)
       },
       error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(errorThrown);

       }
   })
}

render() {
    return(
        <div><h1 id={'name'}>{this.state.username}</h1>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.click_btn}>show</button>
        </div>
    )
}
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<User/>,document.getElementById('root1'));
```

insert.php file:

```
<?php
 echo json_encode(array('name'=>'Jack'));
```

I have used both fetch() as you can see in my code(commented) an jquery ajax , but both trigger error function.

```
 console.log(errorThrown.toString());//show nothing
 console.log(textStatus)// error
```

Comment: The `error` callback has **three** parameters: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

Comment: If you have an error, probably a good idea to include its text in your question, do you think?

Comment: I think the Issue is  response parsing

Comment: Is this not a copy/paste of your actual code?  Because you're missing a closing quote here `dataType:'json,`

Comment: @Patrick Q, yes, it's not

Comment: @Jmx  Please provide an exact copy/paste, as that is the only reliable way for us to know what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I added the header to my PHP file:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  echo json_encode(array('name'=>'Jack'));
```